# Unable to use  mirror up mode and wireless remote on a D7000

Tags: remote, wireless, mirror

I am trying to use the mirror up mode on my D7000 with a wireless remote but I can't get it to work no matter what.

Has anyone used the remote and the mirror up mode successfully: if so can you tell me how you did it and/or what settings?

Answer (score 7):

Pretty sure it's not possible with the wireless remote. You can set custom function D11 to ON. D11 is the Exposure Delay Mode, which will flip the mirror up then wait a second and then trigger the shutter.

With this turned on, your wireless remote will work in remote mode and you'll get a 1 second mirror up delay.

Comment: This is correct. Mirror lock up mode is used to gain access to the sensor for cleaning. Exposure delay mode is what the OP needs.

Comment: Mirror up mode is used to help remove all vibrations from mirror flipping up before taking the picture. Used on a tripod, with a wired release. It's the last choice on the D7000 release mode dial. There is an option in the settings to lock the mirror up for cleaning that also removes power from the sensor.

Comment: Semantics I think.

Comment: Not really, the Mirror Up release mode is for long exposures/reduction of vibrations. First click of the shutter release button raises the mirror. The second click opens the shutter for a specified length of time. You are not able to clean the sensor in Mirror Up mode, because the sensor is not exposed when the mirror is raised. In "Lock Mirror Up for Cleaning Mode", the mirror is raised AND the shutter is opened AND the sensor is powered off so you can clean it. One is a release mode, one is a maintenance mode.

Comment: What I mean is, what you are calling 'Mirror Up' release mode used to be called Exposure Delay mode. Po-tay-to po-tah-to.

Comment: In the D7000 - what this question is about - there is a Release Dial. The release dial has Single, Continuous Low, Continuous High, Quiet, Timer, Wireless Remote, and Mirror Up. Mirror Up is a 2 stage shutter release. Also, in the Custom Functions, there is a setting: D11. D11 sets Exposure Delay mode. Exposure Delay mode is a mode that if enabled, will delay the shutter 1 second after mirror up automatically - without the need for a second shutter button press. They are 2 completely different things. One is a mode, one is a setting - that aim to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I'm just trying to keep the operations of the D7000 in regards to "Mirror Up" Release Mode, the "Exposure Delay" setting, and the "Lock Mirror Up for Cleaning" mode very clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Shooting Menu' you can change the remote control mode to 2 second delay, quick response, or remote mirror up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the release dial to "remote" (the little picture of the remote) and then you go into the Shooting Menu (the little camera icon) and then the last option should be "Remote control mode" and then highlight and select "Remote mirror up" (the other 2 choices are "2 second delay" and "quick response")...
With these settings your first press of the remote will move the mirror up, then your second press operates the shutter and returns the mirror back...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  As it explains in the D7000 on section Self-Timer and Remote Modes.  First of all you will find the Remote Control mode display under the Shooting menu.  The shooting menu display three options: select the Remote mirro-up et voilà.  Afterward you make sure to cover the view finder if you are not using it. Turn the release mode dial to the remote control setting.  You need to press it twice: the first time is for locking-up the mirror and the second time is for the exposure.

Answer (score 0):

The camera battery needs to be at 75% or greater for this menu function to operate.

Answer (score 0):

i am using a wireless jyc remote with a 5d markii, to use the mirror lock up on this I set my exposure time settings on the remote then press the main shutter release button on the remote which opens the mirror (ihave enabled mirror lock up in the camera menu first) then i press the timer start button which starts my exposure, including the delay if i have set one.